# Is sharing base and derived class names a bad practice?

Tags: c#, oop

Since people have requested more context, I will try to provide a concrete example of the problem. I am doing some sort of generic ERP system that displays the usage of resources in a diagram. I have some generic classes that are used to model the problem such as `Job`, `Resource`, and `Operation`. Something like this:

```
public class Job
    {
        public string ID { get; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Arrival { get; }
        public Job(string id, DateTime arrival)
        {
            Arrival = arrival;
            ID = id;
        }
    }

public class Resource
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    protected Resource(Resource other) => ID    = other.ID;
    }

public class Operation
    {
        public string ID { get; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Job ProcessedJob { get; }
        public Resource Processing Resource { get; }

        public Operation(string id, Job processedJob, Resource processingResource)
        {
            ID = id;
            ProcessedJob = processedJob;
            ProcessingResource = processingResource
        }
    }
```

However, the application is generic so this modeling may not be enough for all possible problems. For example, there may be Jobs that have properties such as the maximum time they can take to be processed or resources that have a certain schedule. The thing is that depending on the concrete problem I am modeling these characteristics may be part of the problem or not so expanding each class whenever a new problem case arises doesn't seem a good idea since it will pollute the code.

The obvious solution is inheriting from each base class and having a derived class for each problem case so that includes the desired properties, such as `Problem1Job` and `Problem1Resource`. In my opinion, this also gets messy if more problem cases or base classes are added because the total file count increases. An example of this could be (I didn't include constructors for the sake of clarity):

```
public class Problem1Job : Job
    {
        public bool ExtraPropertyA {get ; set; }
        public string ExtraPropertyB {get ; set; }
        public int ExtraPropertyC {get ; set; }
    }

public class Problem1Resource : Resource
    {
        public bool ExtraPropertyA {get ; set; }
        public int ExtraPropertyB {get ; set; }
    }
```

Instead of storing all these classes in one folder, I have decided to group all the base classes in one folder called `base`, with its own namespace, and create a folder for each of the problems with a different namespace. This allows me to create classes that are `Job : base.Job` and `Resource : base.Resource` inside the namespace `Problem1`, thus sharing the name with their base classes but in a different namespace. For me, it is a clean way to organize the files, but I don't know if there is any convention regarding sharing the names between the base and derived classes (given they are in different namespaces) or if it is considered a bad practice/code smell.

Comment: Can you _show_ a code example, rather than only _describing_ your code? Also, real world class names in your example are more beneficial to providing an answer than "foo" and "bar".

Comment: Could you give a bit more context of what you are actually trying? Something a little more concrete? Otherwise it would be difficult to say whether inheritance is the right solution

Comment: Usually it makes sense to name the class by its behavior. So if you in your code is using both case1 and and case2 there is no confusion which class is which.

Comment: You can follow the same pattern as `System.Exception`: There is a base class `System.Exception`, and then derived classes `SomethingException`. So you would have base classes `Job`, `Resource`, `Operation`, and then derived classes `PrintJob`, `PrintResource`, `PrintOperation`.

Comment: The exception case makes more sense since it is just one object that is being inherited from a variety of namespaces/assemblies, but here it seems that in the long run, I will end up having too many classes in the same folder.